# Как в tkinter регулировать размер, цвет, и шрифт текста?

Tags: python, tkinter, текст

Как в tkinter регулировать размер, цвет, и шрифт текста?

Answer (score 6):

При помощи `font` вы регулируете размер и стиль шрифта, а при помощи `fg` вы регулируете цвет шрифта. Подробнее можете посмотреть [вот тут](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/GUI_Help/Tkinter_book#Label)

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
label = tkinter.Label(root, text='Hello word', font='Times 30', fg='#0F0').grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
tkinter.Text(root, font="Courier 20", bg="Black", fg=color)
```

Так можно регулировать и бэкграунд, и шрифт, и цвет текста.