# Как изменить текст в виджете text при помощи wx.FontDialog()

Tags: python, wxpython

Да есть вариант осуществить это через `text.SetFont(font)` но для этого мне надо и виджет text писать при помощи wx, а мне это как раз и не надо.я думаю что `dialog.GetFontData` просто хранит значение , то есть мне нужна команда которая выведет это значение и подставить это в `text.tag_config =`. Но что это за команда такая. В этом мне и нужна помощь.

```
def font_text():
    a = wx.App()
    dialog = wx.FontDialog(None, wx.FontData())
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        data = dialog.GetFontData()
        font = data.GetChosenFont()
        colour = data.GetColour()
        text.tag_config = (data,font,colour)
    dialog.Destroy()
```

Comment: А причем тут `tkinter`?

Comment: дело в том что я хочу изменять текст в виджете text как раз в tkinter, а не в wx, если знаете диалог по смене шрифта в tkinter, то подскажите пожалуйста, а если нет , то помогите разобраться с вопросом описанным выше

Comment: Не совсем понял что вы хотите сказать *диалог по смене шрифта*, но если вас интересует [функция смены шрифта и цвета текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779046/255866)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно получить [`wx.Font`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Font.html) с помощью метода `wx.FontData.GetChosenFont`. Объект `wx.Font` будет содержать всю информацию о выбранном в диалоге шрифте.

```
import wx


class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        btn = wx.Button(self)
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBtn)

    def onBtn(self, e):
        dlg = wx.FontDialog(self)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        font = dlg.GetFontData().GetChosenFont()  # type: wx.Font
        print(font.FaceName)
        print(font.PointSize)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Frame(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```